# Automation Anywhere

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I am doing a research in Automation and would like to know the answers for he following questions

- What kind of version control does the AA support?
- How to insert the new node in XML using AA?
- Which variable in AA is used to store the text which is copied from another application?

Comment: I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not a site where people will do work for you without seeing any effort on your side. All of those questions are really easy and you can find answers for them on the first page of Google search.

Comment: I just want the answers not any kind of advice

Answer (score 1):

- AA supports and suggests an SVN integration, however the control rooms themselves can also provide this capability, should you not require your repository to be distributable or highly available.
- There's a command within Automation Anywhere, bundled with additional XML commands, which is simply titled "Insert Node" which is very simple. Just insert the XPath Expression (ie `//root/test`), the name of the node, and the value for the node and it will append it to whatever XPath you choose.
- All variables hold strings naturally. Clipboard is an option which takes data from where you've copied it. Prompt-assignment is the generic testing variable you can use to store information. Of note: strings containing only numbers must be handled carefully as they are compiled at runtime and you cannot specify ahead of time that they're integers. Output may vary.